# Javascript, mechanics behind pop() and push() in a array sort function

Tags: javascript, arrays, computer-science

I'm working on improving my javascript skills and I want to understand the mechanics behind pop() and push(). I'm reading Marijn Haverbeke's Eloquent Javascript book and I'm working on chapter 4's [Reversing Array exercise](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html). I was able to solve the problem; however, I ran into an interesting quirk. My first code attempt was:

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

function reverseArray(array){
 var newArray = [];
 console.log(array.length);
 for(var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++){
  newArray[i] = array.pop();
 };

 return newArray;
};

reverseArray(arr);
```

This result was ['d', 'c', 'b'] and the the 'a' was not resolving. I don't understand why? Can someone explain?

My second code attempt was:

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

function reverseArray(array){
 var newArray = [];
 console.log(array.length);
 for(var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  newArray.push(array[i]);
 };

 return newArray;
};

console.log(reverseArray(arr));
```

This resulted in the correct reversal of the array: ['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']. Can someone explain why this worked?

Comment: Sure about the order of the first code? it prints ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

Comment: The first function just copies an array...

Comment: There is not much explanation to do. It seems quite trivial: in the second snippet you push the elements in reverse order into a new array.

Comment: Please review the code. I updated it with the correct snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here lies your problem:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++){
    newArray[i] = array.pop();
};
```

for each iteration:

```
i = 0 array.length: 4 //d 
i = 1 array.length: 3 //c
i = 2 array.length: 2 //b
i = 3 array.length: 1 //a -- wont print
```

now your loop stops working because you told so in:-

```
i <= array.length
//3 <= 1 will return false so for loop stops
```

Not sure if you noticed, but `push()` and `pop()` change `.length` property of an `Array`

Answer (score 0):

The first function doesn't return the expected result because as you `pop` its elements it gets shorter. Each turn the loop compares the arrays **new** `length`.

You could store the arrays **initial** `length` and compare against it:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

function reverseArray(array){
    var newArray = [],
        length = array.length;  // save the initial length
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
        newArray[i] = array.pop();
    };

    return newArray;
};

console.log(reverseArray(arr));
```

Comment: Thanks! So what you are saying is, when it pop is applied to the last index, 0 it fails because it registers the length as 0?

Comment: When only 'a' is left the length is 1, but the counter is at 3 so the comparison returns false.